# Combine absolute and relative difference into one metric

Tags: mathematical-statistics, ratio

Imagine we're looking to buy some commodity, say a table, and we want to make a good deal. We know the "true" price of the tables at offer and we're interested in *both* the absolute price difference *and* the relative price difference.

- Table 1 costs €200 but is worth €400 = €200 difference = 50%.
- Table 2 costs €300 but is worth €550 = €250 difference = 55%.

Is there a way to weigh either the absolute or relative difference with the other to create a combined metric for comparing the two tables' prices?

In other words, the solution I'm looking for should differentiate between a €500/€1000 difference and a €50/€100 difference, in favor of the former.